# VB.NET GetObject(,"Excel.Application") fails to get running Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, automation

I have a single, visible, running instance of Excel 2013. I have already performed a Quick Repair *and* an Online Repair, and waited for the Repair to completely finish.

If I run this VBA from Word, I *can* get a reference to the running Excel Application:

```
Sub WordMacro()
  'This works
  Dim o As Object
  Set o = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
End Sub
```

But if I run this from Visual Studio 2013 Professional under .NET 4.5, it fails:

```
Option Strict Off

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim o As Object
        'Cannot create ActiveX component.
        o = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

        'But this does create a new, hidden instance
        o = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Is there some security consideration that I'm missing, or do I just need to do a complete uninstall/reinstall of Office?

Answer (score -1):

In .NET you must run excel.exe before to get instance:

```
Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe", _
            AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus)
Xc = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```